# How do I change my vba code to work with linked tables?

Tags: sql, vba, database

```
   daDB.OpenRecordset("tblStudentScoring", dbOpenTable)
```

This function works well when the tables were local tables. Now I have split the
database with the tables in another file. The vba code can't find the table when I run
it.  How do I fix this problem? I have been looking all over the web, but can't find the
right solution to this problem.  This is the part of the code that fails to open the
linked table
This the code that fails to open the table.